# "React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element" but I'm not using it at anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `staticcontext` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
        at svg
        at SvgIcon (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-act/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:14367:24)
        at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:24127:31)
        at DashboardIcon
        at Route (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80337:29)
        at Switch (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80508:29)
        at div
        at div
        at div
        at div
        at Admin (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/main.chunk.js:11031:173)
        at Route (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80337:29)
        at Switch (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80508:29)
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80019:30)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78856:35)
        at PersistGate (http://localhost:3000/material-dashboard-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:87045:5)
        at Provider
```

`Dashboard.js`:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

////////// REACT PLUGINS FOR CREATING CHARTS //////////
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";

////////// MATERIAL-UI CORE //////////
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Box, Container, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

////////// MATERIAL-UI ICONS //////////
import ArrowUpward from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpward";
import AccessTime from "@material-ui/icons/AccessTime";
import BugReport from "@material-ui/icons/BugReport";
import Code from "@material-ui/icons/Code";
import Cloud from "@material-ui/icons/Cloud";
import FlightTakeoffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FlightTakeoff";
import NightShelterIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NightShelter";
import LocalOfferIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LocalOffer";
import MonetizationOnIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MonetizationOn";

////////// CORE COMPONENTS //////////
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.js";
import Tasks from "components/Tasks/Tasks.js";
import CustomTabs from "components/CustomTabs/CustomTabs.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import CardIcon from "components/Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";
import CardFooter from "components/Card/CardFooter.js";

////////// VARIABLES //////////
import { bugs, website, server } from "variables/general.js";
import {
  dailySalesChart,
  emailsSubscriptionChart,
  completedTasksChart,
} from "variables/charts.js";

////////// STYLES //////////
import styles from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/views/dashboardStyle.js";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

////////// REACT REDUX //////////!SECTION
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

////////// REACT ROUTER //////////!SECTION
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

////////// FETCHING APIS //////////
import {
  getSpecificCustomer,
  getSpecificWallet,
  getAllBookings,
} from "../../crud";

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

export default function Dashboard() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [render, setRender] = useState("all");
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  ///// STATES FOR DISPLAYING NAME /////
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [middleName, setMiddleName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");

  ////////// STATES FOR DISPLAYING VALUE (FLIGHTS && TRAVEL_PACKAGES && HOTEL) //////////
  const [listBookings, setListBookings] = useState([]);
  const [totalPage, setTotalPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalRecord, setTotalRecord] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  ///// STATES FOR DISPLAYING ACCOUNT BALANCE /////
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState(0);

  ///// DISPLAYING DATA AFTER THE COMPONENT RENDERED PERFECTLY /////
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  ///// DEFINING USER BY USERID /////
  const userId = useSelector(
    ({
      user: {
        user: { sub },
      },
    }) => sub
  );

  ////////// INTEGRATTING APIS /////////!SECTION
  useEffect(() => {
    const bookingType = localStorage.getItem("bookingType");
    const bookingDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookingDetails"));
    if (bookingDetails && bookingType) {
      history.push("/customer/booking");
    }

    ///// USER DATA /////
    getSpecificCustomer(userId)
      .then((res) => {
        loadValuesHandler(res.data.data.customer);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          history.push("/401");
        } else {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          enqueueSnackbar("Unable to fetch data.", {
            variant: "error",
          });
        }
      });
  }, []);

  //// USER ACCOUNT BALANCE /////
  getSpecificWallet(userId)
    .then((res) => {
      setBalance(res?.data?.data?.wallet?.balance);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
        history.push("/401");
      } else {
        console.log(error?.response?.data);
        console.log(error?.response?.status);
        enqueueSnackbar("Unable to fetch data.", {
          variant: "error",
        });
      }
    });

  //// FETCHING USER INFO /////
  const loadValuesHandler = (user) => {
    setFirstName(user.firstName ? user.firstName : "");
    setMiddleName(user.middleName ? user.middleName : "");
    setLastName(user.lastName ? user.lastName : "");
  };

  ///// DISPLAYING NUMBER OF BOOKINGS ////
  const fetchData = () => {
    const params = {
      search: '{"query":""}',
      sort: "_id",
      page,
      pageSize: 10000,
    };
    getAllBookings(params)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.data);
        setListBookings(res.data.data.bookings);
        setTotalPage(res.data.data.totalPages);
        setTotalRecord(res.data.data.totalRecords);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          history.push("/401");
        } else {
          console.log(error.response.data);
          console.log(error.response.status);
          enqueueSnackbar("Unable to fetch data.", {
            variant: "error",
          });
        }
      });
  };

  ///// FORMATTING THE NUMBER THAT /////
  ///// IF THE VALUE LENGTH IS IN THOUSANDS /////
  ///// THE VALUE WILL HAVE A K OR MILLION /////
  ///// WITH IT /////
  const formatNumber = (num) => {
    if (num >= 1000 && num < 1000000) {
      return (num / 1000).toFixed(1) + "k";
    } else if (num >= 1000000) {
      return (num / 1000000).toFixed(1) + "m";
    } else {
      return num;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Typography variant="h5">
          Welcome {firstName} {middleName} {lastName}!
        </Typography>
      </Container>
      <Box justifyContent="start">
        <hr style={{ lineHeight: "1px" }} />
      </Box>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="warning">
                <FlightTakeoffIcon />
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Flights</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                {listBookings
                  .filter((bkg) => bkg.lob === "AIR")
                  .map((bkg) => (
                    <span
                      className={classes.tr}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setType(bkg.lob);
                        setRender(bkg._id);
                      }}
                      key={bkg._id}
                    >
                      {bkg.lob}
                    </span>
                  )).length && listBookings.length === 0
                  ? `No Flights Booked`
                  : formatNumber(listBookings.length)}
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>All Tme Book Ticket</div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="success" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="success">
                <NightShelterIcon />
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Hotels</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                {listBookings
                  .filter((bkg) => bkg.lob === "HOTEL")
                  .map((bkg) => (
                    <span
                      className={classes.tr}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setType(bkg.lob);
                        setRender(bkg._id);
                      }}
                      key={bkg._id}
                    >
                      {bkg.lob}
                    </span>
                  )).length && listBookings.length === 0
                  ? `No Hotels Booked`
                  : formatNumber(listBookings.length)}
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>All Time Available Hotels</div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="danger" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="danger">
                <LocalOfferIcon />
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Packages</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                {listBookings
                  .filter((bkg) => bkg.lob === "TRAVEL_PACKAGE")
                  .map((bkg) => (
                    <span
                      className={classes.tr}
                      onClick={() => {
                        setType(bkg.lob);
                        setRender(bkg._id);
                      }}
                      key={bkg._id}
                    >
                      {bkg.lob}
                    </span>
                  )).length && listBookings.length === 0
                  ? `No Hotels Booked`
                  : formatNumber(listBookings.length)}
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>All Time Available Packages</div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="info" stats icon>
              <CardIcon color="info">
                <MonetizationOnIcon />
              </CardIcon>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Your BalancE</p>
              <h3 className={classes.cardTitle}>
                {balance.length === 0
                  ? `No Balance In Account`
                  : formatNumber(balance)}
              </h3>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardFooter stats>
              <div className={classes.stats}>All Time Balance</div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
          <Card chart>
            <CardHeader color="success">
              <ChartistGraph
                className="ct-chart"
                data={dailySalesChart.data}
                type="Line"
                options={dailySalesChart.options}
                listener={dailySalesChart.animation}
              />
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Daily Sales</h4>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>
                <span className={classes.successText}>
                  <ArrowUpward className={classes.upArrowCardCategory} /> 55%
                </span>{" "}
                increase in today sales.
              </p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter chart>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <AccessTime /> updated 4 minutes ago
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
          <Card chart>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <ChartistGraph
                className="ct-chart"
                data={emailsSubscriptionChart.data}
                type="Bar"
                options={emailsSubscriptionChart.options}
                responsiveOptions={emailsSubscriptionChart.responsiveOptions}
                listener={emailsSubscriptionChart.animation}
              />
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Email Subscriptions</h4>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Last Campaign Performance</p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter chart>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <AccessTime /> campaign sent 2 days ago
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={4}>
          <Card chart>
            <CardHeader color="danger">
              <ChartistGraph
                className="ct-chart"
                data={completedTasksChart.data}
                type="Line"
                options={completedTasksChart.options}
                listener={completedTasksChart.animation}
              />
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Completed Tasks</h4>
              <p className={classes.cardCategory}>Last Campaign Performance</p>
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter chart>
              <div className={classes.stats}>
                <AccessTime /> campaign sent 2 days ago
              </div>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
      <GridContainer>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
          <CustomTabs
            title="Tasks:"
            headerColor="primary"
            tabs={[
              {
                tabName: "Bugs",
                tabIcon: BugReport,
                tabContent: (
                  <Tasks
                    checkedIndexes={[0, 3]}
                    tasksIndexes={[0, 1, 2, 3]}
                    tasks={bugs}
                  />
                ),
              },
              {
                tabName: "Website",
                tabIcon: Code,
                tabContent: (
                  <Tasks
                    checkedIndexes={[0]}
                    tasksIndexes={[0, 1]}
                    tasks={website}
                  />
                ),
              },
              {
                tabName: "Server",
                tabIcon: Cloud,
                tabContent: (
                  <Tasks
                    checkedIndexes={[1]}
                    tasksIndexes={[0, 1, 2]}
                    tasks={server}
                  />
                ),
              },
            ]}
          />
        </GridItem>
        <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
          <Card>
            <CardHeader color="warning">
              <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>Employees Stats</h4>
              <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
                New employees on 15th September, 2016
              </p>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={["ID", "Name", "Salary", "Country"]}
                tableData={[
                  ["1", "Dakota Rice", "$36,738", "Niger"],
                  ["2", "Minerva Hooper", "$23,789", "Curaçao"],
                  ["3", "Sage Rodriguez", "$56,142", "Netherlands"],
                  ["4", "Philip Chaney", "$38,735", "Korea, South"],
                ]}
              />
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The code provided, does not appear to have any reference to `staticContext`, so I would say the error is not there.  Looking at your callstack, it appears to be part of some SVG you have included.   Specifically `DashboardIcon`, can you show the code for that.?

Comment: I've looked up my whole project by leaving the node modules aside. I haven't used the word "staticContext" anywhere. The file where I am integrating the APIs "Dashboard.js, Login.js and Userprofile.js" are seen blank while the others are showing off their components.